# Tipo atributo varbinary sql server com c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, linq

Essa coluna `DocumentoPDF` até o momento não era utilizada pelo sistema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja estava sempre `null`, no entanto em algum momento foi adicionado valores e daí então passou a ocorrer erro na minha consulta `linq` e o problema é que no momento não estou utilizando esse atributo:

Essa é a mensagem de erro:

```
"já existe um DataReader aberto associado a este command que deve ser fechado primeiro"
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro já ocorre mesmo antes da execução da consulta linq:

```
IEnumerable<MinhaEntidade> minhaEntidade = new IEnumerable<MinhaEntidade>()
IEnumerable<MinhaEntidade> _dados = from prg in minhaEntidade.listaDados()                                                                               join servicos in _servicos on prg.IdServico equals servicos.Id into outServicos
join servicos in _servicos on prg.IdServico equals servicos.Id into outServicos
from servicos in outServicos.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new ProcessamentoRegistrosDTO
{
Id = prg.Id,
Nome = prg.Nome,
Campo1= servicos.Campo1,
Campo2= prg.Campo2
};
```

Essa é a entidade:

```
public class MinhaEntidadeDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int IdServico {get; set;}
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string SobreNome { get; set; }
        public string DocumentoPDF { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Habilitando [MARS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars) na sua `connectionstring` provavelmente vai funcionar, mas tente identificar onde você está abrindo a conexão e executando mais de um comando nela. Não entendi exatamente onde está ocorrendo o erro pelo que publicou.

Comment: @George Wurthmann editei o pergunta e adicionei uma imagem do erro.

Comment: A causa raíz do problema foi identificado e o problema foi solucionado e vou adicionar a solução ao post.

Comment: O problema é o `tipo` do atributo que esta no modelo de dados da aplicação: tipo `string` e no banco Sql Server `varbinary`, apesar de não utilizar esse atributo em minhas consultas o erro exibido não tem muito a ver com o fato, porém alterei no modelo para `byte[]` e o erro não ocorre mais.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido após alterar o tipo de dado no modelo: de `string` para `byte[]`.